# Flag (IMHO) inappropriate close reasons? Robo-reviewers?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I recently flagged a post in the close queue after seeing quite a few in a row which each had 2 close votes as "primarily opinion based". The reason I did was because it seemed odd that there were so many in a row with the same amount of close votes for the same reason. **And** most I didn't think that most people could see as primarily opinion based even though many probably should be closed for another reason.

I'm just not sure if this creates more unnecessary work for the mods or if it is worth them looking into. I thought it might be worth looking at because if people are now robo-closing then it won't be good for the site if questions are being closed for inappropriate reasons. Users will be confused on what and how to post.

**Clarification**

Thanks to BoltClock, I see I might not have been clear. It's not so much the "wrong" *reason* for the closures that I brought this up but because it seemed to be a trend that may be reveal robo-reviewing behavior. This was the reason for my flag. It seemed fishy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot directly act on pending close/reopen votes except by casting our own vote and reversing it. But in the vast majority of cases, it's usually not worth the effort.

I recommend only flagging to dispute a closure *after* the question has been closed and there haven't been any reopen votes after a reasonable amount of time, because we can then potentially take action as we deem fit.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know if it would help for you to see what's going on, if anything, while it's happening such as seeing a trend of "robo-closers". Because I'm not sure how easy it would be to track this after the fact since I probably won't stumble upon any other time.

Comment: @codeMagic: In that case, you should mention that the reason you're flagging is because the users voting to close might be robo-reviewers. That way we know you're flagging suspicious users and not the close votes themselves, and we know where exactly we should direct our investigations.

Comment: That was the point of my flag but I guess I might not have made it clear. Hmm...too bad I can't edit my flag reason

Comment: Well, now I can't find any of them so that's awkward. I can't believe they were all retracted so I'm not sure what to make of that. Anyway, thanks for the response.